# to allow certain ips and block all other connections on AMAZON EC2 ubuntu 12.04

Tags: linux, iptables, firewall

How do I allow certain IPs and block all other connection in iptables on AMAZON EC2?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can accomplish this using `UFW`.

Enable `UFW` and set **default incoming** to deny:

```
$ sudo ufw enable && sudo ufw default deny incoming
```

Then you can allow specific IP's with:

```
$ sudo ufw allow from 192.168.1.10 to any
```

This will allow IP-address `192.168.1.10` to any port on your firewall.

Comment: ubuntu@master:~$ sudo ufw enable && sudo ufw default deny incoming
Command may disrupt existing ssh connections. Proceed with operation (y|n)? y
Firewall is active and enabled on system startup                                               
Default incoming policy changed to 'deny'
(be sure to update your rules accordingly)
ubuntu@master:~$ sudo ufw allow from 10.9.XX.xxto any
Rule added                             After this if i tried to take new session with putty (from the specific ip which I allowed Ip addresses) I couldn't make it.Any idea ?

Comment: The IP (10.9.XX.XX) you allowed, is that your public IP address?

Comment: I got it now.Will check it with public ip this may work .I have one issue like I denied all incoming connection with private ip so that I couldn't able to take ssh for that instance.Any idea?